# Can you tell me what this drawing is? (Rebus)

Tags: wordplay, rebus

This will be my first Rebus attempt, so hopefully it's not too easy (or too difficult because of the crappy drawing).[image: What would you do for a Klondike Bar?]

Hint:

> The first picture shows a man laying on a bed. The second picture is spiky, and it is not alive (at least, not the way people have been suggesting. It was part of something living, and may hold something that lives inside it). They are found everywhere outside. The third picture shows the dawn of a new day.

Comment: @user477343, It is indeed. Is it really that hard to tell?

Comment: No it's not very hard to tell, but I just wanted to be sure, because I've never seen it drawn in that particular style before, hahah. I will delete my comment, though :P

Comment: @user477343 It's a reggae sunrise! The morning after...

Comment: Is that like a demonic sun or something?

Comment: Is the answer a single word?

Comment: @WeatherVane The answer is two words.

Comment: @North, It's supposed to be a normal sun...

Comment: The middle one is?  i thought that is what he was asking if it was a demonic sun.

Comment: @SteveV, No, the middle thing is something entirely different. I'm not going to say what it is, because that would spoil the riddle, but it is spiky.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know is it rot13(hepuva)?

Comment: @R.D No, it is not that.

Comment: The first and last images are clear enough, but I can only think that the middle image might be a [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)(urqtrubt be cbephcvar)

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails, I'll add more to the first hint.

Comment: Then I know what it is (the face was a bit misleading). Then may I ask if we're to use a US- or UK-specific name for those things?

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails, I'm from the U.S., specifically grew up in Texas. I looked at the Wikipedia page for the second image, and it lists it as what I thought it'd be. I don't think there is another name for them, but I'm not entirely sure. Hopefully, my location will clarify that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the answer...

> Labor Day?

The first image...

> is a person laying down, so **LAY**.

The second image...

> is a **BURR**, [as figured out by Jim W](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/71379/43477).

And the third image...

> is a sunrise on a new day, so **DAY**.

Comment: The answer consists of two words, but you are very close. You've got the first and the second part right. If you're from the U.S., you may want to think of events that just happened recently.

Comment: @gnovice What about rot13(ynobhe qnl)

Comment: @hexomino, that's it!

Comment: @Joe-You-Know: Man, it should have been more obvious to me, being in the states and all. :)

Comment: Ahh you were too quick for me, good job gnovice and Hexomino

Answer (score 5):

Im going to guess the answer is

> Labor Day (Lay + Burr + Day)

First picture

> Lay is the word - Shamelessly stolen from gnovice ( will edit to give you better credit)

Second picture

> A spikey thing (part of something alive but not how people have been suggesting) leads me to believe it is a fruit of the sweet gum tree.  Small and spikey with many holes for a bug or small animal to possibly live.  Its nicknamed a burr ball or gum ball or monkey ball so my guess was burr

Third picture

> You wrote that is was a new day and it needs to be 3 letters so it must be day!

Comment: You've got the second word as intended, but the first and third are different words (though you've got the basic gist of both of them). Both represent short words, three letters each.

Comment: Gnovice beat you to it barely. Good job though! +1 from me.

Comment: We were probably editing at the same time but he was quicker than me hahaha, no worries though :)

Comment: Honestly, I'm just surprised that this one took this long to solve (probably due to my crappy drawing). When I built it, I thought it was super obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> In Unison? (Inn + [Uni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_urchin#As_food) + Sun)

Comment: This is not a bad guess. The second picture is another spiky thing. Also, the rebus is chronological

Comment: What do you mean by that? Like the images on the right are later in time?

Comment: As in to put the answer together, it is read from left to right. ans + w + er = answer. Something like that.

Comment: Ah, that's what I did, but I guess I misinterpreted the images.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that in was part of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the obvious answer.

> A guy is sleeping (maybe on a bed) and then the sun is up and Viola! Good Morning. I think that is the answer.

In simple words-

> A person sleeping is woken up and it is morning and he probably wakes up.

So the answer is-

> **Wake up**

Comment: If that is the answer, then what is the meaning of the second picture???

Comment: Nice guess but Kevin L is right. What does the second picture have to do with this puzzle?

Comment: The second picture is a sun like the one kids make i.e a sun with a smiling face

Answer (score 3):

Super easy

> The first image depicts a man in a sleeping bag so we can assume he is in a tent. The second image shows a big hole in the tent with an angry bear on the other side. The third image shows the opening of the tent in the morning, but we all know the man was mauled to death in his sleep by the bear so it's not some national park we are looking at. The answer to the rebus is hence **HEAVEN**.

Comment: Were you looking at the same pictures? I'll add in a hint to make things easier.

Comment: What the hell XD The second picture is not a bear mate :D

Comment: Oh well, I tried 